# does exporting a javascript object and then modifying that object in that exported file make the modification happen for the exported instance too?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

I have a typescript file main.dev.ts with the following code :

main.dev.ts

```
class Main {
  mainWindow: BrowserWindow | null = null;

  public getMainWindow(): BrowserWindow {
    return this.mainWindow!
  }

  public init() {
    app.on('ready', this.createWindow);
  }

  private async createWindow() {
    this.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      show: false,
      width: 1324,
      height: 728,
      backgroundColor: "#f0f2f5",
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        enableRemoteModule: true
      }
    });

    this.mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html`);

    this.mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.mainWindow?.show();
        this.mainWindow?.focus();
      }, 150);
    });
  }

}


function createMainApp():Main{
  const mainApp = new Main() ;
  mainApp.init()
}

export const mainApp = createMainApp()
```

I have another ts file which imports this exported `mainApp` object.

anotherFile.ts

```
import {mainApp} from 'main.dev'

function myFun(){
  const window = mainApp.window
  //window is "null" even though the main window is already 
}
```

The function `myFun` gets called much later after the main window has been created (in the same main process). Here the window object is `null`.

I thought when we exported the object in the first file , all the state changes of the exported object is retained. What am i missing here ?

Comment: Did you mean `mainWindow`? Also note that calling init just registers an event handler callback, it won't get called straight away.

Answer (score 1):

**To your question**: Yes, imported module uses the same instance over files.

**To you bug**: Problem is because of the way you init your app, not because of imported instance, `createWindow` will be executed with the `this` of the global scope (maybe `window.mainWindow` is what you need).

1. Make sure the event `ready` will be called, and will always be triggered even though the app had already been "ready".
2. The `createWindow` function should be executed under `this` of a Main instance:

```
public init() {
    app.on('ready', this.createWindow.bind(this));
}
```